# Why is the higher order Taylor series less accurate for higher values of z?

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, error-function

So, I've calculated the absolute errors on python for the taylor series 
approximation to the error function.

$P_N(z)=\frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{(-1)^n z^{2n+1}}{n! (2n+1)}$

I've plotted a graph comparing the error for N=4 and N=5, and for lower values of z (the point the function is evaluated at), the error is smaller for N=5, which is what I would expect, but for higher values of z (roughly z>1) the error is smaller for N=4, why is this? It's probably really simple and I'm being thick, but I can't really explain why.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original function is bounded, the Taylor polynomials are not (they are non-constant polynomials after all). The fourth degree approximation grows $\sim z^4$, the fifth degree approximation $\sim z^5$ as $z\to \infty$. Clearly, the $z^5$ term is larger than the $z^4$ for $z$ large enough

Answer (score 1):

In general, a convergent sequence need not behave nicely for the first 5 terms, nor even for the first $1,000,000,000,000$ terms. For example, here is a sequence that converges to $0$:
$$x_1 = 10, x_2=10^{10}, x_3=10^{10^{10}}, x_4=10^{10^{10^{10}}}, 
$$
and more generally $x_n = 10^{x_{n-1}}$ for $n \le 1,000,000,000,000$, and then 
$$x_n = \frac{1}{n} \quad\text{for all}\quad n > 1,000,000,000,000
$$ 
You might say this was a somewhat artificial example, and I agree that it was concocted to make a point, however this kind of "not nice behavior" is nonetheless quite common in more natural sequences.

In particular, and speaking generally although not quite universally, in a convergent Taylor series, the further $z$ is from the center of the Taylor series (in your case, the further $z$ is from $0$), the higher $N$ will have to be before the sequence begins to exhibit "nice" convergence behavior.